# Access object variables in java

Tags: java, object, arraylist, dictionary

If i have

```
public class fakeclass{
int a;
int b; 
//getters and setters etc.
}

fakeclass abc = new fakeclass();
Map<String,List<Object>> tempObject= new HashMap<String,List<Object>>();
tempobject.put("blabla",abc);
```

Making the assumption that all values inside the `tempObject` are of instance type `fakeclass`, how do i access the getters and setters of the class? If i do a iteration, it is of type 'object' and will not display the getters and setters. (unless i change the map type to fakeclass).

just interested in the options to do this.

Comment: You could cast the object to your fakeClass;
I don't know the exact method name for querying a map but for a list you would do:
`int fakeA = ((fakeClass) list.get(0)).getA();`

Comment: "*Making the assumption that all values inside the `tempObject` are of instance type `fakeclass`*" with this assumption you should be using `Map<String,List<fakeclass>>`...

Answer (score 2):

Cast it:

```
((fakeclass)tempobject.get("blablabla").get(0)).getxxx()
```

Note the `get(0)` as the `Map` is of `List`s

Answer (score 2):

if it is sure that the values in the lists are from fakeclass why not

```
Map<String,List<fakeclass>> tempObject= new HashMap<String,List<fakeclass>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fakeclass abc = new fakeclass();
Map<String,List<fakeclass>> tempObject= new HashMap<String,List<fakeclass>>();
//don;t forget the List
List<fakeclass> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(abc);
tempobject.put("blabla",list);
```

Now when you access the List from the map and any objects in that List, then you can use it as type 'fakeclass'.

```
fakeclass retrieved = tempobject.get("blabla").get(0);
//use retreived as a fakeclass with all its setters and getter.
```

But if you must keep the list of type Object, then you can always just cast it.

```
Object retrieved = tempobject.get("blabla").get(0);
fakeclass retreivedFakeclass = (fakeclass) retrieved ;
//use retreivedFakeclass as a fakeclass with all its setters and getters.
```

Comment: The line `Map<String,List<Object>> tempObject= new HashMap<String,List<fakeclass>>();` shouldn't compile. It expects a `List` of `Object` and you give it a `List` of `FakeClass`. Java generics do not allow assignments like this, as `List<FakeClass>` is not covariant with `List<Object>`. The reason is that it is possible to insert a `String` into a `List<Object>` but this is not allowed with a `List<FakeClass>`.

Comment: Yeah so you make an edit change.  You dont downvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the way you call the `put`-method of `Map`, I think what you really want is a `Map<String, Fakeclass>` instead of the `List` inside of the `Map`.

```
public class Fakeclass{
    int a;
    int b; 
    //getters and setters etc.
}

Fakeclass abc = new Fakeclass();
Map<String, Fakeclass> tempObject= new HashMap<String, Fakeclass>();
tempObject.put("blabla", abc);
```

And then you can access the setter/getter of `Fakeclass` using

```
tempObject.get("blabla").getA();
```

Answer (score 0):

These following lines will not compile.

```
fakeclass abc = new fakeclass();
Map<String,List<Object>> tempObject= new HashMap<String,List<Object>>();
tempobject.put("blabla",abc);
```

Are you interest to store List or fakeclass ?

if the below statement true

```
Making the assumption that all values inside the tempObject are of instance type fakeclass
```

you should use like this

```
           fakeclass abc = new fakeclass();
        Map<String,fakeclass> tempObject= new HashMap<String,fakeclass>();
        tempObject.put("blabla",abc);
        tempObject.get("blabla").getA();
```

If your intention is Store List of FakeClass for an String this use the following

```
fakeclass abc = new fakeclass();
        Map<String,List<fakeclass>> tempObject= new HashMap<String,List<fakeclass>>();
        List<fakeclass> list = tempObject.get("blabla");
        if (list == null){
            list = new ArrayList<fakeclass>();
        }
        list.add(abc);
        tempObject.put("blabla",list);
```

if you wish access the getters methods of first element in the list then use this

```
tempObject.get("blabla").get(0).getA();
```